# Add <span> tags using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to wrap the last line of a text in `<span>` tags using jQuery or Javascript?

```css
#myspan{
  color: #db1926;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Here is some text, of which I want the last line to be wrapped in span-tags with id="myspan".<br>If it works this line will color red.
</div>
```

Comment: From where to where do you want to be wrapped in span?

Comment: You can add the span with id where you want it to be, and then get this span with JS or JQuery, and add it your class myspan

Comment: @JayGhosh: It's clear, but only if you scroll right -- there's a `<br>` tag and then the text after it says it should be red.

Comment: If _Crowder's_ answer doesn't cut it, this one does, and if so, also make this question a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120012/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-get-the-last-line-of-a-text-fitted-in-a-fixed-widt

Answer (score 4):

That specific example is quite easy, because the target text node is the last child in its parent; see comments:

```js
// Create the span, give it its ID
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.id = "myspan";

// Get the div
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

// Move the last child of the div into the span
span.appendChild(div.childNodes[div.childNodes.length - 1]);

// Append the span to the div
div.appendChild(span);
```

```css
#myspan{
  color: #db1926;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Here is some text of which I want the last line to be wrapped in span-tags with as id="myspan".<br>If it works this line will color red.
 </div>
```

Or with jQuery:

```js
// Create the span, give it its ID
var span = $("<span>").attr("id", "myspan");

// Get the div
var div = $("#myDiv");

// Move the last child of the div into the span
span.append(div.contents().last());

// Append the span to the div
div.append(span);
```

```css
#myspan{
  color: #db1926;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Here is some text of which I want the last line to be wrapped in span-tags with as id="myspan".<br>If it works this line will color red.
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As [A.Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948093/add-span-tags-using-jquery-or-javascript/40948165?noredirect=1#comment69106677_40948165), that can be a **lot** shorter using `wrap`:

```js
$("#myDiv").contents().last().wrap('<span id="myspan"></span>');
```

```css
#myspan{
  color: #db1926;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Here is some text of which I want the last line to be wrapped in span-tags with as id="myspan".<br>If it works this line will color red.
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See:

- [DOM4](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/)
- [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com)

Comment: As a side note, the jQuery sample could be simplified using `$.fn.wrap()` method, e.g: `div.contents().last().wrap(span);`